# Xamarin Forms can't find how to bind object with a detail view

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I m using Xamarin Forms and I wan't to display the detail of an element after I clicked on it in my list view. It will open a new view with the detail. I don't know how to bind an entire object to a view, to use his properties easily.

Here is my code :

```
   public partial class ContactDetailPage : ContentPage
        {
            public ContactDetailPage(Agency agencyItem)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                // The agencyItem is get from a list view
                // HERE I suppose I need to bind the agencyItem to the view ?
            }
        }
```

Here is my detail view to display an agency :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Class="Project.ContactDetailPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                <Label Text="{Binding agency.name}" FontSize="Micro" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
                <Label Text="{Binding agency.address}" FontSize="Micro" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
            </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

How can I bind the view to the agencyItem to display it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/) on this.

Short answer is:

`BindingContext = agencyItem;`

`BindingContext` is a property on each `Page` which takes care of bindings and such. Note that you don't need to do `<Label Text="{Binding agency.name}" ... />` if name is directly in `agencyItem`. You can just use `<Label Text="{Binding name}" ... />` directly. So start from the root object. If your `agencyItem` has a `String` property `Name`, just use `Name` directly. If the `agencyItem` has a complex property `Agency` which has a `String` property `Name`, then your current binding is correct.

You could also choose to do it in XAML. Then you would have to create a property and implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

I also notice that you're not using a pattern like MVVM. That might be worth looking into as well!

Comment: How does it looks with a MVVM pattern it's a very simple case no ?

Comment: True! If there isn't a use case for it, don't do it! I was just wondering if you knew if it even existed ;) It can have benefits even in a smal project. And of course I am confident your project will grow very large, quickly!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a [ListView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/) and then on its [SelectedItem Property](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.SelectedItemProperty/) (if you are using MVVM) or in the [ItemSelected](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/#selectiontaps) event or [ItemTapped](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/#selectiontaps) event Push your detail page (ie : [navigate](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/#Navigation) to detail page).

You can find samples here :

1. [ListView Sample 1](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ListView/)
2. [ListView Further details](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/)
3. Sample project - [XamarinForms_Dynamic_ListView_Item](https://github.com/rohitvipin/XamarinForms_Dynamic_ListView_Item)
4. [Data Binding](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/#Data_Binding)
5. [Lists in Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/#Lists_in_Xamarin.Forms)